# can't install NUGET hdf5-v120-complete to .NET project with framework 4.6.1

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package, hdf5

I get this error:
Could not install package 'hdf5-v120-complete 1.8.15.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to change to NuGet package HDF5DotNet which works with later frameworks.